# Does Pr(A and B) exist for this set of events?

Tags: probability

- Two events A, B are in an event space such that $Pr⁡(A ∪ B')=Pr⁡(A'∩
     B)$.
- Also, $Pr⁡(B)=\frac{1}{3}.$

I know that $Pr⁡(A'∩ B)$ can be expressed as Pr(B only) = $Pr(B) - Pr(A ∩ B).$

What about $Pr⁡(A ∪ B')$, how do I express that in terms of $Pr(A ∩ B)$?

Then, is there enough information to tell whether $Pr(A∩B)$ exists?

Comment: There is not enough information to find $P(A\cap B)$.

Comment: Of course it exists since $A$ and $B$ are in the event space. Finding its value is another thing.

Comment: @BernardMasse , what if they are mutually exclusive?

Comment: Zero  is a number that exists. We do not do math with Roman numerals any more.

Comment: I am not following. If $A$ and $B$ do not touch each other, then how can their intersection exist?

Comment: The empty set also is a set that exists. It is the intersection of any two disjoint sets. And the empty set usually has probability measure zero.

Comment: On the other hand, since the given conditions lead to a contradiction, *for this set of events* the probability of $A \cap B$ can be anything. For this set of events I can be the Pope, too, and the moon can be made of cheese. (Those things cannot happen, but neither can the given conditions, so it all works out logically.)

Comment: @ShootingStars, if they are mutually exclusive, their probability will be 0, which exists and is a lawful and valid value for a probability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Draw a Venn diagram.

[image]

Since $P⁡(A ∪ B')=P⁡(A'∩ B),$ then $$P⁡(A'∩ B)=\frac12.$$

And since $P(B)=\frac13,$ then $$P(A\cap B)=\frac13-\frac12\\=-\frac16.$$

This is clearly a contradiction, so the given scenario is impossible.

Answer (score 4):

If $\Pr(B)=\frac13$ then $\Pr(B^c)=\frac23$ and we find:

- $\Pr(A^c\cap B)\leq\Pr(B)=\frac13$
- $\Pr(A\cup B^c)\geq\Pr(B^c)=\frac23$

Then evidently: $$\Pr(A\cup B^c)\neq\Pr(A^c\cap B)$$
So the situation sketched in your question cannot occur.